# Volumes of rotation cylindrical shells

Tags: calculus

Problem: The region bounded by the given curves is rotated about the specified axis. Find the volume of the resulting solid.

$x=(y-3)^2$, $x=4$ about $y=1$

My attempt:
I set this up on a graph, but I am stuck on how I should integrate it.  Would the equation of integration be:
$ \pi \int _ 1 ^5 \sqrt(x)+3 dx$
Is this correct?

EDIT: Wrote down the wrong problem.

Comment: I cannot identify the region which is being rotated. Were some of the bounding curves/lines left out?

Comment: That's all the problem says but, when I got $\sqrt{x} +3 $ I believe it is just the real region so x>0 is also another bound. I am also guessing y>1 is another bound.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the problem says only that. A reasonable problem would be to specify additional bounding lines $y=0$ and $y=1$. But that is not specified.

Comment: Ya I realized I wrote down the wrong equation, check again. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture. Note that $x=(y-3)^2$ is a rightward opening parabola, with axis along the line $y=3$. Note that the parabola meets the line $x=4$ at $(4,1)$ and $(4,5)$.

We can use slicing or cylindrical shells. Since shells are specified in the title, we will use that first, and then washers.

Draw a thin horizontal strip of width "$dy$," going from $y$ to $y+dy$, and rotate it about the line $y=1$. The radius of the cylindrical shell is then $y-1$. The "height" of the shell is $4-(y-3)^2$. Thus the volume is
$$\int_{y=1}^5 2\pi(y-1)(4-(y-3)^2)\,dy.$$

Alternately, we can use slicing, with slices perpendicular to the $x$-axis. The cross-section at $x$ is a "washer."

From $x=(y-3)^2$ we get $y=3\pm \sqrt{x}$. The outer radius of the washer is $3+\sqrt{x}-1$, that is, $2+\sqrt{x}$. The inner radius is $2-\sqrt{x}$. So the volume is
$$\int_{x=0}^4 \pi\left((2+\sqrt{x})^2-(2-\sqrt{x})^2\right)\,dx.$$
Note that the integrand simplifies to $8\pi \sqrt{x}$.